# Bones are invisible and background screen in Solid View is too bright

Tags: 3d-view, bones

I was working on this lego character from a course online. I created a new 2D Animation layout, the way the instructor from the course had done. I created a basic idle and running animation and saved it. I did not work on the project for about 2 days but when I opened the same file, I cannot see the bones of the armature.

The 2D animation layout had about 6 Editor types:

The right hand corner is a slim section divided into the Outliner at the top, and the Properties below it.

In the center, it is divided into 2 main sections:

The one on top is divided vertically in the middle, with a 3D viewport on either side. The left one displays the camera's view focussing on the face of the humanoid model (for 2D animations using grease pencil) and the one on the right is a perspective view of the entire model.

Below this sections I have two editos split horizontally. The one on top is the Grease Pencil Dope Sheet, and the one below is the Action Editor Dope Sheet (the default type).

[image: The custom layout setup]

Now, all the editors seem to be working fine except the 3D viewport displaying the entire 3D model. In Solid View, the entire background is a much brighter colour than what it used to be; and all the custom object shapes that I had created for each of the controlling bones in the armature is missing. It is not hidden in the outliner, nor is any object in the scene in Local View. So I do not understand why it's invisible, and how to revert the background colour. Moreover, I used to be able to see the floor in the Right Side View but now, unless it's in Perspective view, I cannot see it.

[image: The Viewport is way brighter (more white than grey), and I cannot view the custom bone shapes that I had created.]

However, if I go back to the Modelling or Layout Tab, the Viewport background is the default colour and the custom bone shapes are visible as well.

[image: The custom bones are visible and the viewport background is back to the default one]

I use Blender 2.8 for this project and I have attached my project file. Any help to revert these issues is appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51727

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I have now added the images.